# Jquery how to use <ul data-role="listview"> to display listview?

Tags: javascript, json, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a html page and I want to parse a JSON file to display. I want to display in a listview format by using Jquery mobile script. But I don't know why I can't make into a list view, am I using the  correctly?

here is my javascript in html

```
$.getJSON('http://www.sfu.ca/~cniu/data.json', function(data) {
var output="<ul data-role="listview">";

for (var i in data.quiz){
    output += "<li id='link"+ i +"' onclick='loadReadyPage("+ i +")'>"+ data.quiz[i].quizName +"</li>";
}
output +="</ul>";
document.getElementById("quizList").innerHTML=output;
});
```

Comment: Theres a nice example here --- http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8uac7/

Answer (score 2):

In the last line you are adding the listview element dinamically to the DOM, but you are not calling the method to enhance it with jQuery Mobile:

```
$('#quizList ul').listview();
```

If you later change its content, you have to refresh it:

```
$('#quizList ul').listview('refresh');
```